# Blender Still Image Rendering with Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, blender

I have been searching the web for this and haven't found any solid ideas how to perform this task.

#### My Requirements

These are set:

- Hadoop mapreduce
- Blender
- Any software/libraries must be open source

#### The Project:

I am using python to generate a scene in blender.  I have this working perfectly and creating a camera path.  When i open the blend file created in UI everything is as it should be.  I am currently rendering with python into still images but even after reducing quality settings I am still rendering at 1 frame per second.  After all the still images are rendered I am animating the frames into a sequence with blender.  All of this is working stand alone but it takes about 5 minutes to render a 30 second video.

#### The Goal/Problem:

I need to render the camera path and output the result into a video format.  On a single machine as you are probably very well aware a 1 minute video can take a very long time to render and I will be rendering varying length videos from seconds to possibly an hour long.  The idea is to use hadoop to distribute the rendering across a cluster to reduce the render times.

I am somewhat familiar with mapreduce but am not sure how i can break down this problem into chunks.  I am looking for ideas how to approach this problem to improve render times.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with mapreduce and don't think it will fit into what you want to do - at least not with existing solutions.

What you want to look for is called a render farm. This is where multiple machines each render a portion of the final result. For animations this is easily split by having each machine render a different frame, there are also ways to split up a still image to have parts rendered by each machine.

For a quick start, there are commercial render farms like [Render Street](https://render.st) that have machines setup to do the rendering for you, or free services like [sheepit](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/) that distribute rendering among users computers.

If you have several *nix machines available with blender install on them, you could use [blender's cli arguments](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) to render different frame ranges on each machine.

```
ssh m1.local 'sh -c "blender -b myanim.blend -s 1 -e 10 -a"'
ssh m2.local 'sh -c "blender -b myanim.blend -s 11 -e 20 -a"'
```

To run your own render farm, for a simple farm with admin, there is the [network render addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender) that is included with blender, for a more advanced solution look at [flamenco](https://www.flamenco.io/).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think I can work with this to get started at least.  The hadoop cluster is provided to me, but I can get blender installed on all nodes.  You definitely have me pointed in the right direction and i thank you.